# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 when using nighly version of MobileVLCKit

Tags: ios, swift, vlc

I downloaded nightly version of MobileVLCKit: http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/ios/

When I drag MobileVLCKit.framework to my Swift project and run, I get an error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

I tried to use cocoapod instead of nighly version, all work fine except mp4 audio : "Codec not supported - VLC could not decode the format mp4a (MPEG AAC Audio)"

---

**Update:**

I solved my problem by dragging MobileVLCKit.xcodeproj to my project instead of using nightly version and adding DynamicMobileVLCKit.framework as Embedded binary

Instead of doing this i want to use Static Framework, i run this command `./buildMobileVLCKit.sh -f` and i got those files :

[image]

What files i need to add to my project ?

Comment: What is your deployment target set to ? iOS 9.2 ?

Comment: Deployment target is iOS 8.2

Comment: When i use cocoapod all work fine but i have problem with mp4 audio (mp4a AAC) but when i use remove cocoapod and use nighly version i have problem of Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Comment: What's your problem with mp4 audio ? If it works with Cocoapod, I suggest you should keep using it

Comment: I have this error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IbMGa.png

Comment: I think cocoapod is old that why i wanted to use nighly version

Comment: Any solution for mp4 audio ?

Comment: Mh no I'm sorry, I don't know what you could do.

Comment: Do you still need the answer for now?

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs to link the VideoToolbox framework as you integrate VLCKit as a static library. As you don't link the required framework, linking fails.

Comment: Thank you it work when i add VideoToolbox framework but now i get an error when i play my video (check my update post)

Comment: Sorry, as I said in the other thread, you *NEED* to do a bug report with sample media. This won't solve itself magically in a SO thread!

Comment: When i run "DropIn-Player" in Examples_iOS all work fine.
I wanted to do the same, so i dragged MobileVLCKit.xcodeproj to my project but i can't play videos
"DropIn-Player" is objective C and use libc++.tbd but my project is swift and use libstc++.6.tbd , it can be the problem ?

Comment: i solved my problem, but now i want to use static framework
check my post i updated it